# Updating an input and triggering an action button inside an observer

Tags: r, shiny

I have an application which utilizes an `actionButton` to apply a filter selection to a plot. The application also contains a reset `actionButton` which resets the drop-down selector to its original value, in this instance `mpg`.

I would like to know whether it is possible to have the reset button not only update the selector itself, but then trigger the apply button so that the plot is reverts back to showing `mpg` as the y-axis value as it did at initialization.

Please note that the application must utilize the `reactiveValues` construct shown below as that is present in the actual business use case.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  ## input and output ui elements and apply/reset buttons
  selectInput("var", "Select Y-Axis Variable", c("mpg", "hp", "wt", "am")),
  actionButton("apply", "Apply"),
  actionButton("reset", "Reset"),
  plotlyOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ## stored default values
  plot_vals <- reactiveValues(y = "mpg")
  observeEvent(input$apply, {
    plot_vals$y <- input$var
  })
  ## render plot
  output$plot <- renderPlotly(
    mtcars %>% 
      plot_ly(x = ~disp,
              y = ~get(plot_vals$y),
              type = "scatter",
              mode = "markers")
  )
  ## update selectors (how can I have this segment not only update the drop down, but also trigger the apply button?)
  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    updateSelectInput(session = session, "var", selected = "mpg")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just update the `reactiveVal` on reset:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  ## input and output ui elements and apply/reset buttons
  selectInput("var", "Select Y-Axis Variable", c("mpg", "hp", "wt", "am")),
  actionButton("apply", "Apply"),
  actionButton("reset", "Reset"),
  plotlyOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ## stored default values
  plot_vals <- reactiveValues(y = "mpg")
  observeEvent(input$apply, {
    plot_vals$y <- input$var
  })
  ## render plot
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    mtcars %>% 
      plot_ly(x = ~disp,
              y = ~get(plot_vals$y),
              type = "scatter",
              mode = "markers")
  })
  ## update selectors (how can I have this segment not only update the drop down, but also trigger the apply button?)
  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    updateSelectInput(session = session, "var", selected = "mpg")
    plot_vals$y <- "mpg"
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Smh. Can't believe I missed such a simple solution. Thanks as always for your help